# How to access camera in iphone app (capturing image and showing gallary)

Tags: ios, camera

I was wondering how their is no sufficient resources for camera api of iOS .

```
I want to use camera api in me iphone app .

I have  2 basic requeirment .


 1. want to capture image .
 2. want to see that capture image into gallery.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of resources, you better search around before posting such questions.

Have a look at [Camera Programming Topics for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)